The meaning of orthagonal in a general vector space
I am reading Graph Theory by Bondy and Murty. On page 65, it says the cycle space and the bond space are orthogonal. What is the meaning of orthogonal here? The cycle space and bond space are subspaces of the vector space $\mathcal{E}(G)$ of all subsets of the edge set $E$ of a graph $G$. The vector space is over $GF(2)$ and the addition is symmetric difference.
Edit:
Let $G$ be a graph. Let $\mathcal{E}(G)$ be the set of all subsets of the edge set $E$ of $G$. Then $\mathcal{E}(G)$ is a vector space over $GF(2)$ where the addition is symmetric difference and $0X=\emptyset$, $1X=X$ for $X\in \mathcal{E}(G)$. The set of all even subgraphs (the edge sets of the subgraphs) of $G$ forms a subspace $\mathcal{C}(G)$ of $\mathcal{E}(G)$, called the cycle space of $G$. The set of all edge cuts of $G$ forms a subspace $\mathcal{B}(G)$ of $\mathcal{E}(G)$, called the bond space. What does it mean for two vectors in $\mathcal{E}(G)$ to be orthogonal?

I found a supplemental text online. It seems that the cycle space they define is not the $\Bbb{Z}_2$ cycle space that we're familiar with, and instead involves "circulations", which are a type of real-valued functions on the vertex set. I can't immediately spot a connection between this and the binary cycle space.

Let $E(G)={e_{1},\ldots,e_{m}}$. Then each $X\subset E(G)$ can be written as $a_1{e_1}+\cdots+a_m{e_m}$ where $a_i\in GF(2)$ and the addition is symmetric difference. Does "$a_1{e_1}+\cdots+a_m{e_m}$ is orthogonal to $b_1{e_2}+\cdots+b_m{e_m}$" mean $a_1b_1+\cdots+a_m b_m=0$?

The elements of $\mathcal{E}(G)$ are subsets of $E(G)$. We can thus view $F\in \mathcal{E}(G)$ as an indicator function $E\to \mathbb{F}_2$, taking the value $1$ if $e\in F$, and $0$ otherwise. Then, for two elements $F, F'$ of $\mathcal{E}(G)$ to be orthogonal, we mean
$$
\sum_{e\in E(G)}F(e)F'(e) \equiv 0 \mod 2,
$$
and we denote this sum by $\langle F, F'\rangle$. In plain English, this means $F$ and $F'$ are orthogonal if and only if $F$ and $F'$ have an even number of edges in common. As an example with respect to the cycle and bond space, any cycle intersects any bond in an even number of edges, meaning any cycle is in $\mathcal{B}^\perp$.

Thank you. Is there any reference for this definition?

@Delong my answer is basically paraphrasing of Diestel's graph theory.
